# How node script can run in my current bash context (process)?

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, shell, process

In `bash` You can `source` or `.` to run some bash script in your current context. So if you have e.g. file `foo` with `alias bar='echo bam'` in it and when You run it like

```
$ . foo
```

it will *source* this alias from file `foo` into your current context.

I know if I normally run node script with first line like `#!/usr/bin/env node` then this script is run in sub-shell or as separate process. I want to avoid this and make node script act on my current bash process (context).

How can I run node script that alter my current bash context?

*ps: Any example is good. Node script can only change my directory but again it must happen in my current bash context.*

*ps2: Sub question: If it's impossible in node (and it's very hard for me to  believe in this) or it's very complicated then is it possible in other language? Like PHP, Java, Ruby (I don't ask for C because it's obvious :) and if so please give me some example.*

Comment: You can replace your current running programm in your process with `exec`, but then your process will run node, and bash will be gone from the process, thats not what you want, right?

Comment: That's the problem I don't want to bash be gone. I want to be able alter my current bash context then finish my script and still be in the same bash context only with my script changes.

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled with this same problem when writing [my Node implementation of `wd`](https://github.com/greg-js/wdn). AFAIK there is no way to do what you want to do for reasons already known to you. However, if you want to use node in a sourced shell script, there is a way around it, kind of.

So you can't source a node script, but what you can do is execute node scripts in a sourced shell script. Performance isn't great, but it works. For example, you can't put `process.chdir('/tmp');` in a node script and expect it to change the current working directory in your current process. But what you *can* do is make a node script that `console.log`s a directory and execute that in a *sourced shell* script with something like `cd $(node myscript.js)`. For an example of this, check out the code in my project I linked above. There I use a bash function to source a shell script of a globally installed npm module which then executes JS to change the current dir (at least, in bash and zsh). It's not exactly pretty, but it works.

I know it's not the answer you were looking for, but it's as close as I've found a way to use node to manipulate the current bash context. I actually found this question because I was just trying to refactor and look for a better way to do this.. If I ever do find that better way I'll let you know ;-)